# How to reconnect to redis using java with vertx?

Tags: java, database, redis, connection, vert.x

**The application I'm working on doesn't reconnect with the redis server if the server goes down**.

When my application goes up and the redis server is still not running, my application tries to reconnect until the server runs and they connect. But when the two are connected and the redis server goes down, my application does not try to reconnect and starts giving an error
[ httpStatus: 500
message: "Redis connection is broken." ]

I created an endpoint that makes requests to redis as a test and I'm running the server on my machine and this is the test environment I'm using.

I tried to configure the connection using RedisOptions from the io.vertx.redis.client package but without success. Can you help me please!

code:

```
private final RedesOptions options = new RedesOptions()
private Redis redisClient;
         

private void createRedisClient(Handler<AsyncResult<Redis>> handler) {
                Redis.createClient(vertx, options)
                        .connect(onConnect -> {
                            if (onConnect.succeeded()) {
                                this.redisClient = onConnect.result();
                                //make sure the client is reconnected o error
                                this.redisClient.exceptionHandler(e -> {
                                    // attempt to reconnect
                                    attemptReconnect(0);
                                });
                            }
                            // allow further processing
                            handler.handle(onConnect);
                        });
            }


  private void attemptReconnect(int retry) {
    if (retry > MAX_RECONNECT_RETRIES) {
        // we should stop now, as there's nothing we can do.
    } else {
        System.out.println("erro de conexao >>>> " );
        // retry with backoff up to 10240 ms
        long backoff = (long) (Math.pow(2, Math.min(retry, 10)) * 10);

        vertx.setTimer(backoff, timer -> createRedisClient(onReconnect -> {
            if (onReconnect.failed()) {
                attemptReconnect(retry + 1);
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

and call this method createRedisClient in the constructor of the class.

code:

```
 createRedisClient(onCreate -> {
        if (onCreate.succeeded()) {
            System.out.println("conectado com sucesso >>> " + onCreate.result());
            log.info("Redis Connected: "+onCreate.result());
        } else if (onCreate.failed()) {
            System.out.println("erro de conexao >>>> " + onCreate.result());
            attemptReconnect(0);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue recently. And I believe you are pasting the officially suggested reconnection code from the vertex docs as me:

- https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-redis-client/java/#_implementing_reconnect_on_error

I can verify your case and I opened an issue with a reproducer at [vertx-redis-client #issue 375](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-redis-client/issues/375).

The maintainers did not respond to me yet while I found a solution for this - use `endHandler` instead of `exceptionHandler` like:

```java
//make sure the client is reconnected o error
this.redisClient.endHandler(e -> {
    // attempt to reconnect
    attemptReconnect(0);
});
```

This works perfectly when there are network issues with the redis server or the redis server is temporarily done for a short time. The `endHandler` is called in `RedicConnectionManager`:

```java
      netSocket
        .handler(new RESPParser(connection, options.getMaxNestedArrays()))
        .closeHandler(connection::end)
        .exceptionHandler(connection::fail);
```

The `exceptionHandler` also need to be declared at the same time to handle case described in [vertx redis client #issue 227](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-redis-client/issues/227).

I think the official docs may need some improvements.

Comment: Good news, the [pr](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-redis-client/pull/377) to improve the example Redis reconnection code is merged. It may take days before this change gets applied to the [live docs](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-redis-client/java/#_implementing_reconnect_on_error).

Comment: The demo code is published to official docs as vert.x 4.4.2 was released today.